# Is there anyway to take pictures of the face in a determined size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-resizing

Well, i'm using this code to take pictures, but i would like it to take the picture, then resize it in a determined size, for example, i need that data of the 10 pictures with the same size for training PCA face recognition and i need images with 112 x 92 pixels. Do anyone knows how to do that?

```
import cv2
import time

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/alvaro/Desktop/Pruebas Algoritmos/PCA/DetecRostro/opencv-master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num = 0 

while num<1:

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    x = 0
    y = 20
    text_color = (0,255,0)

    cv2.imwrite('opencv'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame)
    num = num+1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `cv2.resize()` ?

Comment: But i would like that the algorithm take pics of the face